# What does a comma in a parenthesis mean in the AT&T syntax for x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode

What does `(register1, register2, 4)` mean in AT&T assembly?

For example:

```
cmp %eax, (%esi, %ebx, 4)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The complete AT&T base/index register syntax is:

```
offset(base, index, multiplier)
```

Your `offset` field is `0`, so you just have the `(base, index, multiplier)` part.  In your case, you're comparing the contents of the `eax` register to the 32-bit value located at `esi + (ebx * 4)`.

In the Intel syntax you might be more familiar with, this would be written as:

```
cmp [ebx*4 + esi], eax
```