# x86 assembly gcc calling conventions esp register

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Documentation says that when assembly method is called first argument should be at `4(%esp)`.
If so is the second argument at `8(%esp)`?

I really don't get the gnus at&t assembly syntax so what is this following code equal to in intel syntax?

```
4(%esp)
```

Is it `[esp + 4]` or `[esp * 4]` for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003894/what-is-the-0x10-in-the-leal-0x10ebx-eax-x86-assembly-instruction, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650093/what-does-a-comma-in-a-parenthesis-mean-in-the-att-syntax-for-x86-assembly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289472/cmp-in-x86-with-parentheses-and-address

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`4(%esp)` is equivalent to `[esp + 4]`, so assuming your first argument is 4 bytes, your second argument should be at `8(%esp)`

Answer (score 1):

depends on type of first argument - different data types require different amounts of space. If you pass an argument which takes more than 4 bytes, there is no way it can be squeezed into a space with the size that the next argument begins 4 bytes beyond first argument.

Comment: My assembly method takes two arguments and both are of type `uint8_t` so should I use `[esp + 4]` to retrieve the first argument and `[esp + 12]` for the second?

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer no, uint_8 is 8 bits, it may be aligned to 4 bytes, so it's still 8(%esp)

Comment: @Simon So I should use `[esp + 4 + nthArgument*argumentLengthInBits]`?

Comment: stack pointer aligned to 4 bytes means,  a multiple of 4 bytes is used as displacement. esp+4, esp+8, esp+12...

Comment: @Bushmills Roger that :)