# What does a hexadecimal number, with a register in parenthesis mean in Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, disassembly

`lea    0x1c(%ebp),%eax`

So, I understand vaguely what the lea instruction does, and I know those are registers, but what is this structure: `0x1c(%ebp)`? I got this code out of objdump.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMP in x86 with parentheses and address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289472/cmp-in-x86-with-parentheses-and-address)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is one of the many x86 [addressing modes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax). Specifically, this is referred to as "displacement" addressing.

Since you said you used objdump and didn't specify that you used the `-M` flag, I'm going to assume this in the [GAS syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler) (as opposed to [Intel syntax](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm)). This means that the first operand is the source, and the second operand is the destination.

The `lea    0x1C(%ebp),%eax` instruction means, "Take the value in %ebp, add 0x1C (28 in decimal), then store that value in %eax".

Comment: _"as opposed to Intel or AT&T syntax"_ You mean _"as opposed to Intel syntax_"? The code shown is in AT&T syntax.

Comment: @Michael Yup. My bad. I fixed it.