# AT&T x86 Assembly "lea 0x0(%esi,1),%esi"

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I failed to find any documentation on the output of objdump. 
In an objdump -D output, I see below asm but I do not understand it:
lea    0x0(%esi,1),%esi

From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax I can see there are 4 parameters in the "pointer":
segment:displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)

But what does this 0x0(%esi,1) mean? scalar is omitted as 0?
And could any please help to direct me the location of a manual of AT&T asm?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Well, the number outside the parenthesis can only be the displacement. Inside the parenthesis the only thing that can be a number is the scale. So... :) It is just objdump being pedantic.

Comment: When you use a scalar value of 1 (and a displacement of 0) with a single register it is assumed that the register specified is the base. In effect `lea 0x0(%esi,1),%esi` is the same thing as `lea (%esi),%esi` . You can also get `objdump` to output the instructions with Intel syntax which may be more familiar to you. You can do that by adding the option `-Mintel`

Comment: That's a 3-byte NOP, IIRC.

Comment: @MargaretBloom and Michael Petch, thank you. However, Michael, you might be wrong by saying "it is assumed that the register specified is the base.". Please see my last comments to the answer. It should be the offset that is omitted - I think. ;)

Comment: @ninjalj, thank you, but I do not understand why you say 3-byte NOP: the original code looks like:`11db5259:       eb 11                   jmp    11db526c\n
11db525b:       90                      nop\n
11db525c:       8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,1),%esi\n
11db5260:       83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx\n
11db5263:       83 fb 08                cmp    $0x8,%ebx\n
` I only see 1 NOP.  :S

Comment: It does nothing, thus it is a NOP. It isn't the `NOP` instruction, but it is a no-operation. Clearly, this is a 5-byte NOP: the `NOP` instruction (1 byte) plus the 4-byte effective-NOP instruction that follows it.

Comment: To put it simply, `lea esi,[esi]` will change only `eip` register (flags and `esi` will remain the same) and take some cycle(s) of CPU (maybe not really, if the pipeline is in parallel also executing following code, then the cycles are not wasted, only the pipeline actually executing the "nop-ish" `lea` is busy), that's what "nop" instructions are used for, not changing CPU state except advancing it to next instruction. (and from your "dump" it looks as 4 byte "nop", not 3 :) )

Comment: @CodyGray, and Ped7g, thank you for the explanation! Now I understand what you mean by "effective-NOP". it's strange why this was added by the compiler. I know the NOP is usually to give some CPU cycle to do sync or for memory align, but what does this lea instruction mean? Also for this purpose? Do you have any hints?  :-)

Comment: @StevenDing: that NOP is used so some subsequent instruction, typically the target of a jump, is aligned at some nice boundary to improve performance.

Comment: @StevenDing : You may have to read what I said again. I stipulated "When you use a scalar value of 1" . Scalar of 1 is an exception with AT&T syntax where the first parameter can be left off. You can't leave it off with scalars other than 1. This is because multiplying by 1 doesn't actually matter whether it is applied to a base register or offset register since the computed value will be the same either way. This doesn't apply to 2,4,8. You should get an error if you used something like `0x0(%esi,2)`

Comment: Also should point out that `lea 0x0(%esi,1)` and `lea 0x0(,%esi,1),%esi` should produce a different encoding. The former should emit a smaller instruction encoding than the latter, as the latter also encodes the displacement of 0x0 in the instruction. Although a different encoding the instructions do the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thank you for the detailed explanation! Now I understand it is a special case in which the scalar value is 1. But from my understanding, why it did not allow 0x0(%esi,2) to mean (0x0 + %esi + 2 * 1), where 1 is omitted? As you said, multiplying by 1 doesn't actually matter so the factor 1 should be omitted rather than a offset. :-p Maybe some historical reasons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a hexadecimal number, with a register in parenthesis mean in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735903/what-does-a-hexadecimal-number-with-a-register-in-parenthesis-mean-in-assembly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0x0` is a displacement and when it equals to zero, it means that it can be omitted. `1` is a scale and when equals to 1, it means that it can be omitted too. So this instruction `lea 0x0(%esi,1),%esi` is the same as:

```
lea esi,[esi*1+0x00]
lea esi,[esi]
```

Comment: Thank you, S.MAHDI! Now I understand it's the same as "lea esi,[esi]". So you mean the **base register** is omitted in this case, right? Another comment from Margaret and Michael indicated the omitted one seems to be offset? It seems interesting on this point - different people have different understanding, but finally goes to the same result.  ;)

Comment: S.MAHDI et al, with your help, I looked back at the GAS_Syntax page in my question, and now have deeper understanding. It reads: **Either or both of the numeric, and either of the register parameters may be omitted**. And an example without the base is like **leal    8(,%eax,4), %eax**. However, for this one, it must be the **offset** that is omitted. Thank you all~

Comment: Nice to heart that my answer helped you.

Comment: `lea esi,[esi*1+0x00]` and `lea esi,[esi]` are not quite the same. Although both will have the same effect - the second one is actually a shorter instruction as the displacement of 0x00 won't be encoded. `lea 0x0(%esi,1),%esi` should emit the same as `lea (%esi),%esi` which would be `lea esi,[esi]`. `lea 0x0(,%esi,1),%esi` (note the extra comma) should produce the same as `lea esi,[esi*1+0x00]`