# What does comma separated bracket mov instruction mean in disassembly

Tags: disassembly

```
   0x7f52379dc42c:  mov    0xc(%r12,%r11,8),%r11d
   0x7f52379dc431:  mov    %r11d,0xc(%rsp)
   0x7f52379dc436:  mov    0xc(%r12,%r10,8),%r14d
   0x7f52379dc43b:  cmp    %r11d,%r14d
```

I understand that ***mov    %r11d,0xc(%rsp)*** means *(rsp+0xc) = 0xc

What does  ***mov    0xc(%r12,%r11,8),%r11d*** mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a comma in a parenthesis mean in Assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650093/what-does-a-comma-in-a-parenthesis-mean-in-assembly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general syntax for a memory operand (dereference) in AT&T x86/x64 mnemonics is `offset(base, index, scale)`, which is the same as `[base + index * scale + offset]` in Intel syntax (which is almost the same as the pseudo-C syntax you used).

Specifically, your first instruction

```
mov 0xc(%r12,%r11,8), %r11d
```

is the same as

```
mov r11d, DWORD PTR [r12+r11*8+0xc]
```

in Intel mnemonics, and approximately the same as

```
r11d = *(r12 + r11 * 8 + 0xc)
```

in the pseudo-C syntax.

Note that the scale is encoded using only 2 bits in the instruction, and is always a power-of-two, so only values of 1, 2, 4, and 8 are permitted.